# mysql client: change output columns separator

Tags: mysql, mysql-cli

Thought of this to be a very basic issue which people would have definitely faced. But unfortunately, I couldn't find a solution for this after searching a lot.

I am using mysql command line client to run a query, and later on parse the output as per my requirement. By default, it returns output as `tab separated`. And some of the columns of the table have tabs in it.

Because of this, I am not able to parse it properly as the `tab`s in column data are not escaped. When I `cut` my output for `tab`, I get more columns then expected.

I will be using `select * from table` type queries. So replacing `tab` column wise in query is not an option.

Checked at mysql [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html) for any available option but there doesn't seem to be any. Any way to solve this?

Comment: Have you looked at mysql outfile eg http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1475/save-mysql-query-results-into-a-text-or-csv-file/, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html

Comment: Btw, in the output the tabs in the field values should be escaped (unless you use the raw option), so should not cause much of an issue.

Comment: Was trying on remote RDS. So `-B` is the option I used.